# Automatically make heading font size proportional to body text in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like the change the heading styles in Word 2010 so that the font of the heading is always 1/2 a point larger than the body text.  Is there a way to make this automatic, so that if the user increases the size of the body text, the heading will automatically change accordingly?  I know how to edit heading styles and hardwire the font size, by not to make them proportional to the body text.

Answer (score 0):

The way I know is by selecting all and applying the decremental/incremental format buttons. This way all is changed proportionally..

[image]